# Not reading from stdin properly

Tags: c, unix, stdin, eof, cat

I'm trying to mimic the behavior of the unix utility cat, but when I call a command of the form:

cat file1 - file2 - file3

My program will output file1 correctly, then read in from stdin, then when I press EOF, it will print file 2 then file 3, without reading from stdin for the second time.

Why might this be?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define ASCII_LENGTH 255
int printfile(FILE *source, int N);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int currentarg = 1; //the argument number currently being processed

    FILE *input_file;
    //if there are no arguments, dog reads from standard input
    if(argc == 1 || currentarg == argc)
    {
        input_file = stdin;
        printfile(input_file,0);
    }
    else
    {
        int i;
        for(i = currentarg; i < argc; i++)
        {
            printf("%d      %s\n",i,argv[i]);
            //if file is a single dash, dog reads from standard input
            if(strcmp(argv[i],"-") == 0)
            {
                input_file = stdin;
                printfile(input_file,0);
                fflush(stdin);
                fclose(stdin);
                clearerr(stdin);
            }
            else if ((input_file = fopen(argv[i], "r")) == NULL)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s: No such file or directory\n", argv[0], argv[i]);
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                printfile(input_file,0);
                fflush(input_file);
                fclose(input_file);
                clearerr(input_file);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int printfile(FILE *source, int N) 
{
    //used to print characters of a file to the screen
    //characters can be shifted by some number N (between 0 and 25 inclusive)
    char c;
    while((c = fgetc(source)) != EOF)
    {
        fputc((c+N)%ASCII_LENGTH,stdout);
    }
    printf("*****    %c     %d",c,c==EOF);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't suppose you considered looking at [the source code for cat](http://www.scs.stanford.edu/histar//src/pkg/cat/cat.c)

Comment: `fopen` fails for many reasons other than `ENOENT`.  Check the documentation for `strerror` and `perror`.  Don't make up reasons: let the system tell you.

Comment: You close `stdin`, no wonder it is closed the next time around ;-)

Answer (score 4):

For one thing, you can't expect to be able to read from `stdin` after you've closed it:

```
            fclose(stdin);
```

Answer (score 1):

`fflush(stdin);` is undefined behaviour, as is `fflush` on all files open only for input. That's sort of like flushing the toilet and expecting the waste to come out of the bowl, because `fflush` is only defined for files open for output! I would suggest something like `for (int c = fgetc(stdin); c >= 0 && c != '\n'; c = fgetc(stdin));` if you wish to discard the remainder of a line.

Furthermore, `fgetc` returns `int` for a reason: Inside the `int` will be an `unsigned char` value or `EOF`. `c` should be an int, not a `char`. `EOF` isn't a character! It's a negative `int` value. This differentiates it from any possible characters, because successful calls to `fgetc` will only return a positive integer rather than a negative `EOF`. `fputc` expects input in the form of an `unsigned char` value. `char` isn't required to be `unsigned`. Providing your `fgetc` call is successful and you store the return value into an `int`, that `int` should be safe to pass on to `fputc`.